# Oracle PL/SQL: Passing input data from a procedure to a function to insert into a table

Tags: oracle, input, plsql

I have a package that has one procedure and one function. The procedure gets the name of the employee as an input and the function should insert it into the employee table.

```
create or replace package body Emp_Name_pkg is

procedure get_emp_name (p_emp_name VARCHAR(20)) 
is
....
end get_emp_name;

function insert_emp_name is
insert into Employee (Emp_Name) values p_emp_name;
end insert_emp_name;

end Emp_Name_pkg;


This gives me an error - 
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
Errors: check compiler log
```

Now, even after declaring the p_emp_name in the function, after executing the program, it does not display the value for employee name in the table.

I am getting the input through a concurrent program, adding employee name as the parameter there and getting its value through the code but I am not able to do it. The name is not coming up in the table.
How do I get the value for the name from the procedure to the function and eventually insert it in the table since that's my ultimate goal.
And I cannot use insert in the procedure, I HAVE to get input from procedure and insert using a different function.

Comment: You didn't declare any input parameter for a function so it cannot recognize `p_emp_name`

Comment: Even after doing that, it takes a null value and not the one I passed as input. I have written this in the description below the code.

Comment: The code provided is not a working code so it's hard to tell what is wrong.

Comment: Please post a demo of the approach that isn't working. I would expect the function to have an input parameter the same as your procedure, and then it would refer to that parameter within an `insert` statement.

Comment: You said: "I cannot use insert in the procedure, I HAVE to get input from procedure and insert using a different function" - why is that so? Functions usually *calculate* something and return the result. Procedures insert data into tables. Although function can perform insert, you can't use such a function in a SELECT statement. Therefore, why do you **have to** do it that - unusual - way?

Answer (score 1):

`insert_emp_name` should be a procedure, not a function. Because no results are being returned anyway.

```sql
procedure insert_emp_name(p_emp_name varchar2)  
is
begin
insert into Employee (Emp_Name) values p_emp_name;
end insert_emp_name;
```